# How to display data from mvc controller using angular2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I have created a project including angular2 for front-end and i also created webapi project to consume data from database.
Controller Code return model:

```
UserInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UsersVM>>(Response);
```

I want to iterate over this data model in my angular view. i trid creating angular http calls. but this not acceptable in my case. i need to call webapi from my mvc controllers and just to render that data from angular2 views.

Angular Model is :

```
export interface IUser {
Id: number;
ProductName: string;
ProductPrice: string;
```

}

Angular Service Code is:

```
import {
Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
Http, Response, RequestOptions,
Request, RequestMethod, Headers
} from '@angular/http';
import {
   IUser
} from './user';

import {
Observable
} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
private _productUrl = 'Home/GetAllProducts';  
constructor(private _http: Http) { }   
getProducts(): Observable<IUser[]> {        
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IUser[]>response.json().value)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
 }
```

Stuck in this, any links available in google doesn't correctly solve my issue.
Please guide.
Thanks

Comment: I think that you need to call the complete URL like: http://localhost:PORT/Home/GetAllProducts

Comment: What is the error you get?
Also, you should use the new http api instead of the old one: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: i am having correct data in my mvc controller method, i want to bind that and loop over using angular2, the this is i am new in angular2.

Comment: @krunalpatel "this._productUrl" should be actual 'hosted path of api' + 'route path of api' for example. "http://localhost:50962/products/getdetails/1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned `_productUrl` as your API path, but it should be actual API URL with domain name and action call.

as :

```
private _productUrl = 'localhost:50962/products/';
```

Eg.

> Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions,Request, RequestMethod, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { IUser } from './user';    
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private _productUrl = 'localhost:50962/products/';

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }   

  getProducts(): Observable<IUser[]> {   

    let header = this.initHeaders();
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header, method: 'get' });

    return this._http.get(this._productUrl + 'getAllProducts', options)
        .map((response: Response) => <IUser[]>response.json().value)
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private initHeaders(): Headers {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return headers;
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

Also you can set environment variable for your API and use it in all your services.  `environment.API`

```
export const environment = {
  API: 'http://localhost:50962/',
  WordPressAPI: 'http://localhost:58451/',
  FacebookClientId: '45******',
}


return this._http.get(environment.API + 'products/getAllProducts', options)
        .map((response: Response) => <IUser[]>response.json().value)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) and the [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

```
<div *ngFor="let user of getProducts() | async">
    {{user.Id}}
    {{user.ProductName}}
    {{user.ProductPrice}}
</div>
```

Comment: asuming that you have a component that uses your service and with this template, yes

Answer (score 0):

A combination from both (use full path) Amol Bhor & Leon, and instead has the uri vars into env file use constants.ts file because for me environment is related to dev or prod environments. And to avoid memory leaks use asyn pipe, if not use unsubscribe into onDestroy method. Check docs for detail info.

Comment: Correct. It make sense and best practice that for every service and data call's from 'component.ts' we should use unsubscribe() using Subscription class.